# Add Native View in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

i would like to add a TextInputEdit text in my Xamarin.Forms project, is possible to add in code or in XAML? i need to add reference to Mono.Android dll?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[Customizing an Entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry)** to realize it .

[image]

Creating the Custom Entry Control :

```
public class MyEntry : Entry
{
}
```

Consuming the Custom Control:

```
<ContentPage ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomRenderer;assembly=CustomRenderer"
    ...>
    ...
    <local:MyEntry Text="In Shared Code" />
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

Creating the Custom Renderer on Android :

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyEntry), typeof(MyEntryRenderer))]
namespace CustomRenderer.Android
{
    class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        public MyEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.SetBackgroundColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.LightGreen);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is [the official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/customrenderers-entry/) for reference.